# Problem serving static files with express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, create-react-app

i have read some several articles about how to serve static files from create-react-app with express. I have tried everything now. Can someone please help me?

This is how my structure looks like

[image: My project structure]

When i deploy this to Heroku i get following error: `main.ac4887ed.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Why is this happening? I have tried for some hours now.. Maybe something im missing?

This is the code i have in my `server.js` file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("../build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build", "index.html"));
});
```

My index.html file in public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
     shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/quiz.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>QuizGame</title>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the output from Heroku logs look like this when i try to enter the page:

[image: Heroku output logs]

Am i doing anything wrong?

This is index.html from my build folder:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/quiz.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><title>QuizGame</title></head><body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.ac4887ed.js"></script></body></html>
```

This is my package.json file to show dependencies, does it require any dependencies to make it work?

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.17.1",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"immutable": "^3.8.2",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.19.2",
"mongoose": "^5.0.2",
"morgan": "^1.9.0",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport.socketio": "^3.7.0",
"react": "^16.1.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
"react-countdown-now": "^1.3.0",
"react-dom": "^16.1.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
"ws": "^6.1.0"
},
```

Comment: index.html file contains no <script>

Comment: What should i put in there ? First time im doing this :/

Comment: This likely means that index.html differs from the one you posted (it looks like a template for built index.html). If there's no <script>, there's no way how React app (main.ac4887ed.js) can be loaded. Post index.html from /build folder instead.

Comment: I added new line on my post with index.html from /build folder @estus

Comment: I see. The error is caused by that `/index.html` is served instead of `/static/js/main.ac4887ed.js`. This will happen if /static/js/main.ac4887ed.js is missing in /build . I'm not aware why this may happen with create-react-app. Make sure that main.*.js file is there and make sure that * is same as in <script> tag. Rebuild the project if needed.

Comment: Im really sorry but i did not understand what you meant :( @estus

Comment: I'm not sure how to say this in a simpler way. There should be .js file and the error suggests that there's no .js file. Consider providing a way for other users to replicate the problem - a repo or something.

Comment: Is it possible to show you my repo? its private so hard to show it without making it public, i can add you ass contributor if its not problem for you?

Comment: I added my package.json too so you can see my dependencies i have, am i missing some dependencies ?

Comment: No, there's no problem with deps. It would be better to show it to all users, not only me. If you don't have errors when it's built (this could possibly result in missing JS), a repo can be just 'hello world' react app. Notice that https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for SO questions, otherwise they are considered off-topic and can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

In my `server.js` file I changed

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("../build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build", "index.html"));
});
```

to

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use('/', express.static("build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  }); 
}
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a deployed app with create-react-app. Here are some differences between my setup and yours that you might test:

```
    if ( process.env.MODE !== 'development')
        app.use( express.static( `${__dirname}/../build` ) );

    if ( process.env.MODE !== 'development') {
        app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')); 
        });
    }
```

- I'm using absolute path for both the static path and the get endpoint
- These blocks are separated, I'm placing the static middleware before all other middleware, and the get * endpoint at the very bottom of the server file. Only app.listen() is below that.
- You'll also notice I'm using path.join rather than path.resolve, and appending one sole argument to __dirname

Make sure you do `npm run build` and restart the server when it's done.

Comment: Still same problem with unexpected token :/

Answer (score -2):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var path = require("path");
var jsonServer = require("json-server");
app.use(express.static("files"));
app.post("/mm", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/files/hey.`enter code here`html")));
});
app.use("/api", jsonServer.router("./db.json"));
app.listen(9924, () => {
    console.log("hello");
});
```